# Migrate Oracle BLOB to Postgres BYTEA or OID

Tags: postgresql

After the BLOB columns of Oracle (11g r2) tables are migrated into a Postgres (9.4.5) table such as using Ora2Pg, I have two questions:

1) Which data type will the new column assume, is it BYTEA or OID?

2) Will the (BLOB) data be copied over correspondingly?  Or I need to do a separate migration of the data?

Comment: for (2),  what is your max blob size?

Comment: `bytea` is definitely the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

1) `BYTEA`.  Because `oid` is an unrelated concept.

2) Work mostly out of box, see https://github.com/darold/ora2pg/issues/100 .